# How do you make a function accept multiple types?

Tags: go

I am having a function like this:

```
package main
import "flag"
import "fmt"

func print_out_type(x anything) string {
    switch v := x.(type) {
        case string:
             return "A string"
        case int32:
             return "An Integer"
        default:
             return "A default"
    }
}

func main() {
    wordPtr := flag.String("argument1", "foo", "a String")
    numPtr := flag.Int("argument2", 42, "an Integer")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println("word: ", *wordPtr)
    fmt.Println("number: ", *numPtr)
}
```

I am trying to return different types of strings based on the type. I am just stuck at the point of how do I write a function that accepts arguments of different types.

Comment: `func print_out_type(x interface{}) string`

Comment: Use `interface{}` as the type. This is an empty interface; any type implements it. Be sure to complete any decent tutorial on Go as this is a pretty basic thing.

Comment: what about accepting only int + string for example?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use interface types as arguments, in which case you can call the function with any type that implements the given interface. In Go types automatically implement any interfaces if they have the interface's methods. So if you want to accept all possible types, you can use empty interface (`interface{}`) since all types implement that. No other modification needs to be done to your function.

```
func print_out_type(x interface{}) string {
    switch v := x.(type) {
        case string:
             return "A string"
        case int32:
             return "An Integer"
        default:
             return "A default"
    }
}
```

You can also use the reflect package to study the type of an interface variable. For Example:

```
func print_out_type(x interface{}) string {
    return reflect.TypeOf(x).String()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(print_out_type(42))
    fmt.Println(print_out_type("foo"))
}
```

Will print

> int
>
> string

Comment: How can get the value that was sent to the variable and use it in the function? I am using data := x.(ConcreteType) but this will have the scope of switch statement and I can't use it outside that scope

Answer (score 10):

Starting with Go 1.18. you can use generics to specify which types can be used in a function.

```golang
func print_out_type[T any](x T) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%T", x)
}
```

https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics

Answer (score -5):

You can use an `interface{}` type variable as a parameter to the function. In the function, you can use type assertion or type switch to check the parameter's real type and print it out.