# How to write a function that accepts any map

Tags: go

I tried writing this:

```
func KeyExists(m map[interface{}]interface{}, k interface{}) bool {
    if _, ok := m[k]; ok {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

When trying to run this with an `m[int]int`, I get:

```
cannot use xxx (type map[int]int) as type map[interface {}]interface {} in argument to KeyExists
```

Why? From this: [How do you make a function accept multiple types in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145569/how-do-you-make-a-function-accept-multiple-types-in-go)
I infer that interface{} should work here.

The error message is half helpful and half annoying, since it states I cannot do something but not why.

Answer (score 1):

Map types in Go are not [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), and therefore not assignment compatible. Moreover, the empty interface, `interface{}`, does not provide generics. In Go v1, your `KeyExists` function must be implemented for each concrete map type you wish to inspect.

Less formally, given a map of type `map[int]int`, it is not possible to assign to a map whose key or element types are dissimilar, such as `map[interface{}]interface{}`. This holds even if the underlying key or element types are themselves mutually assignable (e.g. it is possible to assign a value of type `int` to a value of type `interface{}`).

Note that you *can* assign any map to a value of type `interface{}` ([example](https://play.golang.org/p/93Z8IUxoa8o)), because all types implement the empty interface. Such assignments are permitted according to the language spec's rules on [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability). However, this is unlikely to be helpful.